# django request.POST.items() returns empty list everytime with Postman

Tags: django, postman

I have a django method and I'm just trying to pull out a POST variable:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_backer(request):
    for k, v in request.POST.items():
        print(k, v)

    email = request.POST.get("email", "none")

    return JsonResponse({"data":{
        "email":email
    }})
```

When I try to do a POST via javascript XMLHttpRequest, I wasn't getting the data through. So I fell back to Postman to try to confirm things are working on the django end. And I am posting the data, but django isn't seeing it. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

[image]

Edit: Interestingly enough, if I change it to GET instead of POST, it works as I would expect.

Comment: For GET it is working because you are passing email data in the url string. For POST, you don't need to do that.

Comment: You need to pass the email data into the request body for POST request.

Comment: POST required passing csrf_token also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `POST` request values are sent in request `body`. You can use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type so that request body has same format of query params.

[image]